# List/Source for SMS Stock/template messages

Tags: templates, sms, message

I am developing an application that communicates via SMS. I want the user to be able to choose from a set of "Stock Messages" for example.

- "I will be with you this morning"
- "I can do this job next"
- "I have arrived on site"

Is anyone aware of a list of this kind of template / stock message/ canned messages for use in a business context. We can obviously come up with a list ourselves but if there was a list of commonly used messages freely available it would increase our chances of generating an appropriate list ourselves.

Comment: I don't see how this question has to do with programming *at all*.

Comment: Well it doesn't have anything to do with "programming" per-se but it is the sort of question that programmers may know the answer to, hence the reason for asking on a programmers web site. I could have asked on IMDB but I thought I may have more luck here

Answer (score 1):

This will really be dependent upon the business use cases the users will be executing. Your examples appear to be for on-site service personnel, in which case investigating the various processes the personnel have to perform should provide you with a basic list.

You would ideally be spending a *lot* of time with the end users, the on-site technicians in this case, to determine from the ground what they have to do, edge cases, typical actions, etc. Management may have their ideas about what *should* be done, but the guys on the ground have to make use of this stuff, so you're best off taking their input seriously. Domain Driven Design..

If the software is going to be used by multiple categories of users, you should present the list to each user, or group of users, more focussed to their needs. No point having on-site tech options available for the assistant-to-CEO, and vise-versa.

Providing stock lists of many, many unsuitable options for users is going to make your software unwieldy and irritating to use.